# Unlocking bitlocker from my hard drive

Tags: bitlocker

I was using my hard drive to copy some movies from a friend's laptop. When I inserted the hard drive in my laptop, a prompt message will say that the device is bitlocker protected. I have no idea what bitlocker was. I don't even know why it prompted. I did not even purchase bitlocker.

My problem now is how to unlock it. I have the key as it is shown in that prompt message but I do not know where to get my password. Its not even in my control panel system.

How can I remove the bitlocker from my hard drive? I cannot access my files. All my back up files are there. I hope someone can help me on this. I'm not exactly technology savvy especially when it comes to this kind of software. I hope someone can enlighten me on this one.

Comment: Presumably your friend's computer has bitlocker installed and locked your drive when you installed it on his machine. Take it back to him to remove bitlocker.

Answer (score 1):

Drive is encrypted and it is not possible to access data without password